# Why doesn't TypeScript correctly infer `this` type?

Tags: typescript

Take the following function:

```
function test<T>(this: { value: T }) {
  return this.value;
}
```

If you use `call`, `apply` or `bind` and provide the `this` context, TypeScript won't infer the provided type and it will return `unknown` in this case.

```
const a = test.apply({ value: 1 }); // a: unknown
const b = test.call({ value: 'b' }); // b: unknown
const fn = test.bind({ value: true }); // fn: () => unknown
```

Ok, it could be because `apply`, for example, is declared as `apply<T, R>(this: (this: T) => R, thisArg: T): R`, so it will require you to inform the `R` return type. But if you only explicitly declare the type of the `test` function, you will get the correct type:

```
const typed = (test<number>).apply({ value: 1 }); // typed: number
```

Why does it happen? Why it didn't infer `R` but then when I provided the type it did?

Comment: TS hardly ever performs the kind of higher order generic inference you're looking for, and there is currently no support for this with `bind`/`call`/`apply`. Generic types operating on generic functions tend to erase the generics type parameters in those functions.  There's an open issue at [ms/TS#54707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54707) asking for it but it's not part of the language.   If you use an instantiation expression like `(test<number>)` then it's no longer generic (`T` has been replaced with `number`) and the issue doesn't arise.

Comment: (see prev comment). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `const obj = { value: 123, test }; obj.test() // number` does work fine. https://tsplay.dev/mA2QkW But `apply` and friends are much more tricky.

Comment: @jcalz your answer is very welcome! Unfortunately, there are already several issues on ts github, like the one you mentioned, and there's nothing we can do in the meantime.

Comment: @AlexWayne that's a good way to work around the problem, but unfortunately, I can't use it on my project. I'm doing a JSX project and I'm using `this` to type the input props of a JSX component and because of that, I can't have generic components.

Comment: If you're using functional components there should be no `this` and there shouldn't be problem. If you're using class based components, then well, I'd suggest refactoring to functional components. I suspect this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and there is a better way to achieve your real goal. I'd encourage you to post a new question that shows the problem you are facing with some react components (if React is what you meant by JSX)

Comment: Thank you @AlexWayne. Actually it's not React, it's my own frontend library that I am creating. It's a mix between React and Solid, here is the github repository if you want to check out https://github.com/estrelajs/estrela

Comment: The plan was to force users to use "this" instead of receiving the props via params because if you spread the props it will lose the reactivity. And, I thought it has a better visual and easier way to identify input props on you component by calling `this.data`. Anyway, I will need to either go back to param prop or not support generic components.

Answer (score 3):

The [`bind`/`call`/`supply` support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply) introduced in TypeScript 3.2, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#27028](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028), is not able to really deal with [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) or [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions properly.  According to the documentation, "when using these methods on a generic function, type parameters will be substituted with [the `unknown` type]" (it says the empty object type `{}` but it's been `unknown` since TypeScript 3.5, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30637](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30637)).  That explains the behavior you're seeing. There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#54707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54707) for improved support here, but for now it's not part of the language.

As for why it works with `(test<number>)`, that's an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions), where the specified type argument gets substituted into the generic function type parameter without calling the function.  So `test<number>` is no longer a generic function:

```
function test<T>(this: { value: T }) {
    return this.value;
}
type Test = typeof test // <T>(this: {value: T}) => T

const tn = test<number>;
type TestNumber = typeof tn // (this: { value: number; }) => number
```

It's just the specific function type `(this: { value: number }) => number`, for which `bind`/`call`/`apply` should work as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCoD4AUUAFjGgFyIDeiAbgIYA2IKF2iAvgJRUBQi-iAE4ooIQUmKkAdPSYoA3D3Y8oATwAOKRNnRREAXmQaUcYMl2IA9JcQ4Ck8lVnNWXA7m08ICDMiSHUDEwwEABbACMUQVxFNU1tXQA5MMjBAyNNUz8rG0ISR2pnFkQQiKj5Dm59D1LUoA)